# How to force user css update?

Tags: css, prestashop, browser-cache

I am working on a prestashop e-commerce website. I find that when I make extensive changes to the css, they don't show up unless cache is cleared. How do I ensure that people see the latest version of my website?

Comment: clear the cache in your server

Comment: "Cache busting" by renaming files depending on a change... https://www.prestashop.com/forums/topic/136126-auto-versioning-css-files-force-css-refresh/

Answer (score 1):

You could add a query to your CSS link.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css?v=1.1">
```